# array containing timestamps. push from array when second in current minute = second from each timestamp value in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, highcharts

I have an array containing json data. Each data item has a timestamp field along with a latitude and longitude. I want to plot these points on a highchart on the second of the current minute that matches each second value of the timestamps in the array.

In summary i want to loop over an array and jump into some logic where the current seconds in a timestamp match up to the current second on the clock.

Any ideas greatly welcomed! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post some example code showing what you have tried.  If you aren't sure what that would look like, try posting some example input and output.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your json looks like this

```
[
  {
    time: t,//some date obj
    lat:a,
    lng:b
  },
  ...
]
```

you could write a function that loops through the array to get all the entries that have the same second value as the current second

```
function findSameSecond (jsonArray) {
  //you could pass in some second maybe if you want but ill just find it here
  var currentSecond = (new Date()).getSeconds();
  var sameSecondArray = jsonArray.filter(function(entry){
    return currentSecond === entry.time.getSeconds();
  })
  return sameSecondArray;
}
```